# R character plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, character

How can I get R to count the number of characters with the same name and to plot said characters in ggplot2?

Example:
A classroom has the students with the following names:
Rick
Rick
Bobby
Jill
Jill
Jill
How can I get R to graph the number of each students with the same names?

Sorry for the simple question but I'm new to R and my limited vocabulary in coding limits my ability to use google!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
names <- c("Rick", "Rick", "Bobby", "Jill", "Jill", "Jill")
table <- as.data.frame(table(names)); table
```

The output would look like this:

```
  names Freq
1 Bobby    1
2  Jill    3
3  Rick    2
```

You can plot the table frequency with a simple barplot:

```
barplot(table$Freq, names.arg=table$names)
```

[image]

Or use ggplot2 to achieve a more aesthetic plot as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
names <- c("Rick", "Rick", "Bobby", "Jill", "Jill", "Jill")
dat <- data.frame(names)
ggplot(dat) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = names), fill = 1:3
```

[image]